# Prove that two definitions of an infinite set are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are two definitions of an infinite set:

1) A set is infinite if it is not finite. 
2) A set is infinite is it is equivalent to some proper subset.

The task is to prove that the two definitions above are equivalent. The first statement seems so obvious that I can't quite understand why prove this at all. How should I approach the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: The point is to prove that (2) is the same as (1).  (1) might be obvious, but (2) might be more useful in certain situations.

Comment: What is finite?

Comment: Part of mathematics is also to learn that you need to prove obviously seeming statements. Start with one definition, and try to derive the second, without jumping.

Comment: You have been asked to prove that the two definitions are equivalent.  You have not been asked to prove either of (1) or (2) individually.  They are *definitions*, not statements that you can prove.

Comment: We assume that set S is finite. If we extract a subset of S, it will turn out we can't build a bijection since there will be elements of S that have no matching elements. Then let S be infinite. Then we can extract a denumerable subset A which can be divided into two denumerable subsets A1 and A2. A and A1 are denumerable so we can construct bijection. Therefore, we can construct a bijection between A∪(M∖A)=M and A1∪(M∖A)=M∖A2. But M∖A2 is a proper subset of M. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

First show if a set is finite, then it is not equinumerous any subset.

Next assume the set S is infinite.  Show there is a denumberable D subset S.  Use D to find a proper subset of D that is equinumerous to D and proceed from there to find a proper subset of S that is equinumerous to S.

Comment: We assume that set $S$ is finite. If we extract a subset of $S$, it will turn out we can't build a bijection since there will be elements of $S$ that have no matching elements. 

Then let $S$ be infinite. Then we can extract a denumerable subset $A$ which can be divided into two denumerable subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$.  
$A$ and $A_1$ are denumerable so we can construct bijection. 
Therefore, we can construct a bijection between $A \cup (M\setminus{A}) = M$ and $A_1 \cup (M\setminus{A}) = M\setminus{A_2}$. But $M\setminus{A_2}$ is a proper subset of $M$.  

Is that correct?

Comment: What is M?  What is the bijection?